# Why so many SMGs?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

After a couple hours of playing, I've noticed a trend in Modern Warfare 3 (that I've seen throughout the Call of Duty series as well). While watching the deathcam, I've seen a large majority of players using SMGs.

Why is this?  Do SMGs hold some inherent advantage over the other weapon types, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Could it just be that's what new players start with? As people level up, won't more weapon options open to them?

Comment: Absolutely - new, shiny SMGs to continue using.

Comment: I see more people running around with M4A1s and SCARs than any SMG in this game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure with MW3, as I don't have it, but with CoD4, MW2 etc the reason that an SMG was great, was usually because it is "lighter" than an Assault Rifle and therefore you can sprint longer with it.

So for the more agile players it is preferable to a heavier weapon.

The UMP45 in MW2 was an excellent weapon, especially in Hardcore mode.

Comment: oh, the UMP45 was awesome. that brought back memories.

Answer (score 1):

It also helps that most SMGs have a higher firing rate than most assault rifles (except the FAD), so not only do you run faster, you shoot faster...more rounds on target for the same timed burst.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the popularity of sub-machine guns is because they are lighter, quicker to reload, and half of the SMGs can shoot fairly accurately.